# Connection Refused while loading Cassandra using gremlin

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

I am doing my first steps using Cassandra and TitanDB.
I installed cassandra and it's running:

```
INFO  14:08:06 Node /127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  14:08:06 Netty using Java NIO event loop
INFO  14:08:06 Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-
INFO  14:08:06 Starting listening for CQL clients on /127.0.0.1:9042 
INFO  14:08:06 Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
INFO  14:08:16 Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds

:apache-cassandra-3.3 yse$ !netstat
netstat -an | grep 7000
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.7000         *.*                    LISTEN
```

now on Gremlin:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
```

..
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties:

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.directory=/tmp/titan/es
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=false
index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode=true
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered previously on the Titan [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/SuUdOn3mh2s/vpMAhjSuCgAJ). Titan communicates with Cassandra using Thrift, which is disabled by default on Cassandra 2.2 and higher. Some options are:

-- Update `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml` before starting the Cassandra node

```
# Whether to start the thrift rpc server.
start_rpc: true
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160
```

-- Enable Thift if the Cassandra node is already running

```
$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool enablethrift
```

Keep in mind that Titan 1.0.0 is built and tested against Cassandra 2.1 (see the Titan [version compatibility matrix](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html)), so be cautious about running it against Cassandra 3.3.

Comment: Thanks. I was spending alot of time just to connect those things with Titan. seems like the quickstart is pretty hard

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to connect titan to cassandra instance; this fixed the problem